# Не загружается полностью файл скрипта

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла такая проблема: на сайт ставится скрипт - большой, около 700Кб, при выводе страницы сайта он не грузится полностью. Скрипт берется со стороннего сервера, на сервере он целый, а при загрузке сайта обрезается (видно в консоли). Аналогичные скрипты на других сайтах работают. В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?
Заранее спасибо.

Адрес: http://www.m-artstudio.com/#!sp-r/c1z2f

Comment: Почему вы решили, что он не целый? Всё отдается нормально. И уточните название файла, там есть скрипт и побольше.

Comment: Недокачивается скрипт, лежащий по адресу http://katalogo.ru/partner/script/m-artst_s_colors.js . Увидеть его в исходном коде вряд ли получится, потому что CMSка странная и генерирует страницу js'ом.

Comment: Welcome to JopaScript world.

Comment: в скрипте ошибка, там где-то цена или сумма со значком евро. надо либо значек евро убрать, либо строкой сделать. возможно из-за этого не грузится.  
ЗЫ имхо, сплэш какой-нить нужен, некрасиво все скачет при загрузке...

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. =)  
Да там по-хорошему не сплеш, а переделка всего сайта нужна, но убедить клиента в этом не получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в скрипте:

[image]

Либо уберите значок `евро`, либо добавьте чисто с этим значком в кавычки.

Comment: О, точно, спасибо. =)